# How do I keep my nav bar off of a header image?

Tags: html, css, positioning

So I cant find a way to keep this navbar in my website from automatically putting itself over top of a header image! I try setting the navbar's position to relative, but that doesn't do anything! I wanna keep my header image's position to be both top and left 0, but without setting the images position to absolute, I cannot get the image to stay at 0 top and left on the screen!

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
.header-img {
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar ul li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Official Rusty Ohio Server</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
  <img src="rusty ohio background.png" class="header-img" width="100%" height="95%">

  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>Plugins</li>
      <li>Server Status</li>
      <li>Donate</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is already on top of the image. What you want to do then?

Answer (score 0):

try this in css

```css
    .navbar{
position: absolute;
z-index: 11;
}
.header-img{
z-index:10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a background image which will give you more control over the image re-sizing respective to your container. You can implement something like below to achieve what you want.

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
#header-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.header-img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-kjbnzo2/products/12634/images/13240/LP_8206__81949.1444680903.500.500__96128.1446754363.1280.1280.jpg?c=2");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.navbar {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar ul li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-wrapper">
  <div class="header-img"></div>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>Plugins</li>
      <li>Server Status</li>
      <li>Donate</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```